# React Native element only visible/usable after pressing a button

Tags: react-native, button, state, textinput

New to React Native, having a go at an app idea. Basically I'm just trying to create an TextInput element that appears when I press a Button. Below is my attempt. I'm trying to take advantage of state within my class, but something is off.

Expo is throwing an error of 'null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.isShowingText')'.

Any ideas?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, Alert, Button, ScrollView, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class CoolComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const nameAdd = () =>{
      state = { isShowingText: true };
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', top: 50 }}>
        <Title>Some Title</Title>
        {this.state.isShowingText ? <TextInput></TextInput> : null}
        <ScrollView></ScrollView>
        <Button
          title="Press me"
          onPress={nameAdd}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you handling `state` is wrong

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, Button, ScrollView, View } from 'react-native';

export default class CoolComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        isShowingText: false
    }

    nameAdd = () => {
        this.setState({
            isShowingText: true
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', top: 50 }}>
                {this.state.isShowingText ? <TextInput style={{ width: '50', height: '50', borderWidth: 1 }}></TextInput> : null}
                <ScrollView></ScrollView>
                <Button
                    title="Press me"
                    onPress={this.nameAdd}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: @Steel If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it.